# How to use php heredoc syntax in foreach loop

Tags: php, heredoc

I am facing a problem regarding heredoc syntax in my controller. My controller function is something like this:

```
function active() {
    $userlist = $this->input->post('userlist');
    $userlist = explode(',',$userlist[0]);

    $items = '';

    if( !empty($userlist) ){
        foreach($userlist as $buddy)
        {

            $actv = $this->user_model->check_active_users($buddy);//returns 0 if no results found
            if ( $online_buddies == 0) {
                $items .= <<<EOD
            {
                "fl": "0",
                "fid": "{$buddy}"
            },
EOD;
            }//if returned 0 inactive

        }//foreach
    }//if nt empty $mybuddies

    if ($items != '')
    {
        $items = substr($items, 0, -1);
    }
     header('Content-type: application/json');
?>
{
    "items": [
        <?php echo $items;?>
    ]
}

<?php
        exit(0);

}//end of func active
```

`$userlist` holds the `user-ids`.

`$this->user_model->check_active_users($buddy)` returns 0 if no results found.

I want to get a flag `0` if no results found in database as well as the respective userid.

But,

```
$items .= <<<EOD
{
"fl": "0",
"fid": "{$buddy}"
}
EOD;
```

Here, `fl` returns `0` but `fid` is returning nothing. Have I done something wrong hre `"fid": "{$buddy}"`

Comment: instead of manipulating strings, you should try using native PHP array s and output the final result by `json_encode()`;

Answer (score 4):

```
$html = <<<HTML  //  Set a variable for your dashboard HTML

HTML here...

HTML;  //  This ends the heredoc for now and concludes the HTML to open the PHP back up

//  The follow resumes your pure PHP code
$query = "SELECT * FROM `some_table_in_database`";

$results = mysqli_query($query);


foreach ($results as $record) {

    // Bellow you define the records as variables

    $variable1         = $record->one;
    $variable2         = $record->two;
    // as many variables as you would like

    $html .= <<<HTML //  Now, you have to concatenate to your $html variable (adding on to it) some more HTML

    HTML here....

HTML;  //  Now we need to switch back over to PHP, so we close the HTML for now

    //  Begin more PHP code here for further use down the page

    $html .= <<<HTML  // We open back up the HTML variable to put more HTML in our page

    HTML here...

HTML;  // and this concludes the HTML.  You can keep going on for ever like this alternating between PHP and HTML code in order to get for and foreach loops and such to cooperate.
```

Comment: My above code gets broken up a bit from Stack Overflow code highlighter, but the <<<SUPPLIERDASHBOARD heredoc opener and the SUPPLIERDASHBOARD; closer are the parts you want to pay attention to.  Notice how they are concatenated.  Breaking them up carefully around the PHP script, and using them around the HTML heavy chunks.

Answer (score 1):

A heredoc seems like it is a bit much for the content you are creating. So why not do something like this instead:

```
$items .= '{
           "fl": "0",
           "fid": "' . $buddy . '"
           },'
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but consider this:

```
// Build the list of items
$items = [];
foreach($userlist as $buddy) {
   $items[] = [
      'fl' => $this->user_model->check_active_users($buddy),
      'fid' => $buddy
   ];
}

// Finally output the items
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(['items' => $items]);
```

Depending on your comfort level with PHP you could also use an array_map to convert the userlist into the items array. My advice though is stick to what you can read and maintain. Example:

```
// Build the list of items
$items = array_map(fn($buddy) => [
   'fl' => $this->user_model->check_active_users($buddy),
   'fid' => $buddy
], $userlist);
```

or if you want to get really clever and cause yourself future problems you can do it all in one:

```
// Finally output the items
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(['items' => array_map(fn($buddy) => [
   'fl' => $this->user_model->check_active_users($buddy),
   'fid' => $buddy
], $userlist));
```

I don't recommend this final approach as it looks like a formidible chunk of code and it's hard to work out what it does.